# Error when uploading files to wordpress even with propper folder permission

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I Just installed a new wordpress into a EC2 Server using Bitnami.

I tried to upload an image but I'm getting the fallowing error:

> logo.png 
>   Unable to create directory uploads/2018/07. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

By using SSH I already give all permissions to the ENTIRE wp-content folder (yes I was desperate)

```
total 32
drwxrwxrwx  8 bitnami daemon 4096 Jul 21 19:57 ./
drwxrwxrwx  6 bitnami daemon 4096 Jul 23 19:48 ../
drwxrwxrwx  2 bitnami daemon 4096 Jul 21 16:20 ai1wm-backups/
drwxrwxrwx  4 bitnami daemon 4096 May 23 18:34 languages/
drwxrwxrwx 14 bitnami daemon 4096 Jul 22 12:39 plugins/
drwxrwxrwx  9 bitnami daemon 4096 Jul 23 02:34 themes/
drwxrwxrwx  2 bitnami daemon 4096 Jul 23 02:34 upgrade/
drwxrwxrwx 10 bitnami daemon 4096 Jul 21 16:20 uploads/
```

What can be happening???

A despite of, the directory 2018/07 already exists

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-56-156:/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/2018$ ll
total 40
drwxrwxrwx  6 bitnami daemon   4096 Jul 23 19:45 ./
drwxrwxrwx 10 bitnami daemon   4096 Jul 21 16:20 ../
drwxrwxrwx  2 bitnami daemon  12288 May  7 23:22 04/
drwxrwxrwx  2 bitnami daemon  12288 May 28 15:25 05/
drwxrwxrwx  2 bitnami daemon   4096 Jun 26 10:36 06/
drwxrwxrwx  2 bitnami daemon   4096 Jul 23 19:45 07/  <<<<<<<<
```

Comment: You should be able to get this working by using the following command `sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads`

Comment: @FahamShaikh did you noticed that permissions was set to 777 ? changin the user and group to daemon does not have any effect. I got the same error

Comment: Yes, I did noticed the permissions. I have faced similar issue on AWS and GCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution.
The problem was on settings, the "media save folder" was misconfigured by the previous administrator. I just removed the setting and it woks.

another option is removing this entry on wp_options mysql table